# Objective C: How to list set of locations with the nearest geolocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, geolocation, geocoding

I have compiled a list of locations with latitude and longitude information. Can I check what is the best approach to filter and populate the list of "nearest" geolocations in a table and mapview based on my current location? (or a destination entered by a user). Also is it also possible to indicate what is the radius I am interested in? e.g. only select all the nearest bookstores within 5km from my location etc

Appreciate your advice on this

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just add your locations to a mapView, and center the map on the user's current location or whereever they want?  MapKit will do all the calculations for you, and only show the ones near the center. The user can set their own radius by zooming in and out.  MapKit is highly optimized for exactly this purpose, that's how you can see the "rain of pins" in real time.

Update:
You can also go the other way: once you have the annotations on the map, you can query the map for those annotations that are in the visible region with:

```
- (NSSet *)annotationsInMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
```

From the docs:

> This method offers a fast way to retrieve the annotation objects in a particular portion of the map. This **method is much faster** than doing a linear search of the objects in the annotations property yourself.

Comment: @Mike, this sounds like what I need :). Can I check with you how I can trigger this? I can add all the annotations to the mapView at launch (around 1000+), how do I not show all 1000 but only those near the user's location? I am now using core data to store all the coordinates of the places I want to show. Thanks!

Comment: You can specify the map's display area with setRegion:, centered on the user's loc,  and the map will only show those in the visible region.   Set the span to adjust the effective zoom level.

Comment: @Mike, thanks! Can I just confirm how I should implement the method? I did something like this NSSet *nearby = [self annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.frame]; But this is causing the program to crash. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're passing a self.mapView.frame, which is a CGRect (which uses CGFloat inside) and you need to pass an MKMapRect (which uses doubles inside).  Look up MKMapRect in the docs.

Comment: P.S. Whenever you say "it crashed", you should also supply information on how and where it crashed; there are an infinite number of ways things can crash.

Comment: @Mike, apologies for that. I am now able to run the app using the line: nearbySet = [self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect]; However, the set returns me nothing. Is there something else I need to set up before this will work?

Comment: Are you seeing your annotations on the map?  Did you add the annotations?  Verify that your self.mapView isn't nil, and that your map is visible.

Answer (score 3):

You may find `- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location` to be very useful
[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)

Answer (score 1):

The [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is frequently used to in navigation for calculating distances between coordinates.  [This](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) is a pretty decent resource for distance calculations, and even has a code sample for haversine (though it is in Javascript).

If your list of locations is relative small (hundreds, even), you can probably just iterate through the whole list and calculate the distance between each place against current location.

Comment: And if the list is quite big, few thousands, you can iterate through them with dispatch_async and inform a delegate when it is complete. :)

Comment: @Radek, yes my list will potentially be quite huge (1000 +), would it be too slow even if I do multi-threading?

Comment: No, iPhones have a fast processor.